# Can I use fine-grained access control in Amazon Elastic Search leveraging an external Access management system?

Tags: security, elasticsearch, amazon-elasticsearch

I am working on a search service.
My Spring Boot search service stands between my internal userbase and my Amazon Elastic Search cluster.
I want to enable [fine-grained access control](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/fgac.html), however I can't rely on AWS IAM as we have an in-house service to manage Authentication and authorization.
Is there any way I can enable fine-grained access control for search without mapping all the users from my system to either IAM, Cognito or Kibana internal database?

Comment: good question! did you find a way forward?

Comment: @Leo since this question has been unanswered for a while, I posted the method we used to get around the obstacle. While not particularly elegant it works and it's secure.

Answer (score 1):

The way we addressed this challenge is:

1. **Create roles and assign permissions to roles.** This is not as
   cumbersome as adding user by user and it can be easily achieved as
   in general there should be just a bunch of roles to be used and
   re-used. Relevant documentation can be found [here](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/security-plugin/access-control/users-roles/).
2. **For each role create one user and map it to that role**. [Here you can find how to do it](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/security-plugin/access-control/users-roles/#map-users-to-roles).
3. **Create service users to be used by applications**
4. **Use service users to impersonate the user** (as per step 2) associated to the role we need. User impersonation docs can be found [here](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/security-plugin/access-control/impersonation/).
5. **Let the calling application to authenticate with the in-house service** and then impersonate the relevant role.

Even if not particularly elegant, this solution works and it's secure.